# Changing JSP url dynamically

Tags: spring, jsp

I am making a program which produces a Random Id and uses that ID in the URL. Now the problem is when I try to access that page or reload that page it says that "Page not Found". My url looks like this: "http://localhost:8080/FinalBrd/event/D8BE8D46".
I want the other users to access the same page with this url. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You need to define the correct servlet mapping for your servlet / JSP.

Comment: @JB Nizet I did the mapping like "@RequestMapping(value="/event/{eventId}", method=RequestMethod.POST).. So I can access the page fine but when I try to reload the page, the contents are not displaying.

Comment: Ah, so you're using a Spring MVC controller. That has nothing to do with JSPs. Use the debugger to find out why. If you want more help, you need to post the code, and to tell precisely what you're doing, what you expect to happen, and what happens instead. Note that "accessing a page using a URL) typically means using a GET request. But you mapped your method with POST.

Comment: Change requestMethod POST to GET.

Comment: @JBNizet changing request mode from POST to GET worked great!! Thanks for the help

Comment: @Harshal Patil thanks for the help... it worked